# Autofac - Resolve Class derived from Generic

Tags: autofac

Having some problems getting Autofac to register my types.

I have the following setup based on another stack overflow post.
[Validation: How to inject A Model State wrapper with Ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776396/validation-how-to-inject-a-model-state-wrapper-with-ninject/4851953#4851953)

My setup is as follows

```
public interface IValidator : IDependancy

public abstract class Validator<T> : IValidator

public class UserValidator : Validator<AccountModel>

sealed class ValidationProvider : IValidationProvider
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IValidator> _validatorFactory;

    public ValidationProvider(Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory)
    {
        _validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
    }
...
```

My Autofac config is

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof (ValidationProvider)).As<IValidationProvider>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .Where(t => t.BaseType==(typeof(Validator<>))).InstancePerDependency()
       .As<IValidator>();

builder.Register<Func<Type, IValidator>>(c =>
{
      var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
      return type =>
      {
          var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type);
          return (IValidator) cc.Resolve(valType);   // failing here
      }; 
 });
```

I can resolve everything except the Func  constructor in the ValidationProvider class. The error I'm getting is

The requested service 'Sw.Web.Validation.Validator`1[[SweepHelper.Web.Models.AccountModel, Sw.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You usage of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` makes me think that it might be the same issue as this question: [Autofac Losing Registrations on Web.Config Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043750/autofac-losing-registrations-on-web-config-edit)